# Testing a form field with a debounced updated value call to a service

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, debouncing

I have a form field (username) in a component that when updated calls a service to check for the value's availability in a database. Everything checks out fine but I can't seem to trigger the field's update function.

Here's the excerpt from the component code:

```js
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.username.update
    .debounceTime(500) // wait 1/2 second before emitting last event
    .distinctUntilChanged() // only emit value if different from last value
    .subscribe((username: string) => {

      console.log('IN SUBSCRIBE'); // <==== This is not being reached in the tests

      let data = { type: 'username', val: username };
      this._loginSrvc.chkUser(data).subscribe((response: IChkUserResponse)=>{
        if(response.isAvailable === false)
          this.username.control.setErrors({'taken': {value: this.username.value}});
      });
    });
 }
```

Here's the field in the component's template:

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" forbiddenCharacters=';"\\\/\[\]\{\}\(\)' required [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" id="username" name="username">
  <mat-error *ngIf="newUserFrm.hasError('required','username')">Username is required</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="newUserFrm.hasError('forbiddenCharacters','username')">{{forbiddenChars.error}}</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="newUserFrm.hasError('taken','username')">The username <em>{{model.username}}</em> is taken</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here's my test:

```js
it('should check for username availability',fakeAsync(()=>{
  spyOn(service,'chkUser');

  let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#username')).nativeElement;
  expect(input.value).toBe('');
  expect(component.username.value).toBe(null);

  input.value = user.username;
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

  tick(500);

  expect(service.chkUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

That last `expect(service.chkUser).toHaveBeenCalled()` is what is causing my test to fail. I've run this component in an application and it works as expected I'm just trying to get the test to pass.  I've tried so many combinations of setting the input value and dispatching the event, waiting on the fixture to detectChanges or using whenStable(), throwing in a promise, using fakeAsync not using fakeAsync. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you sure that subscription is created, that `ngAfterViewInit` gets called?

Comment: Yes, its working in the application, i've tested it manually.

Comment: I mean *in the test*. Have you put any logs in to find out where it's getting? Run a debugger?

Comment: Would this not create the component as if it were instantiated in the application itself: `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewUserComponent);` which in my `beforeEach()`.  How would I test to see if `ngAfterViewInit` was called or not in my test?

Comment: I'm not sure that fakeAsync is applicable here, the test uses real dom and thus really async. Try async() instead, and real delays for this reason. It could be 550 and not 500, as well.

Comment: @estus I've tried that too, I get the same error either way. I've also set tried setting the delay to be 100ms after the actual and still nothing.

Comment: That creates the component, yes. You could test it, as I hinted above, by putting a log in that method and seeing if it gets hit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a `console.log('AFTER_VIEW_INIT')` to the actual `ngAfterViewInit` and it does get called when I run the test.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you did this, too? Did you try detectChanges() before/after tick() in fakeAsync?

Comment: Alright. And did you put any logs in the observable stream with e.g. `.do`? In the callback? Where does it get to?

Comment: @estus yup did that too, tried adding `fixture.detectChanges()` after the input event, after the tick, it is called in the `beforeEach()`.  I've even tried using the `fixture.whenStable()` and the adding the test the callback function of the promise returned by that method.  Still nothing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I added a log call to the subscribe function of `this.username.update` it does not reach that output, so I guess the event isn't dispatching correctly.

Comment: I should add that the service that is supposed to be called is passing all tests and working as it should, separately from this component.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the post to show where in the `ngAfterViewInit` function the test is not reaching.

Comment: do you think you could create a stackblitz with the minimal code to try to recreate this?

Comment: also, try to spy on username.update method, is that being called?

Comment: @BorisLobanov just spied `username.update` its not being called, but I already knew that because the console output in its subscribe function isn't being reached.

Comment: this `input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));` doesn't seem to be triggering the update method.  I've even tried `Event('keyup')`

Comment: @BorisLobanov  I'll see what i can do about getting something up on StackBlitz, but it will have to wait for the time being

Comment: I guess, the sooner you do this the more chances you have of getting help :)

Comment: can you at least post the code for the username.update method? and the username?

Comment: @BorisLobanov there is no code for `username.update` and `username`, `this.username` is a reference to the `ngModel` of the form input control.

Comment: @BorisLobanov `username.update` is an `EventEmitter`

Comment: what's `model`?

Comment: @BorisLobanov https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: **Update** I finally got the subscribe function to fire by doing the following `component.username.update.emit(null);`  but now its saying the service being called is undefined.

Comment: can you show your code that configures your TestBed e.g. `TestBed.configureTestingModule({...})`, suspect your are not injecting dependencies

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is a legitimate question and problem I was having and supplied more than enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my problem after too many hours of frustration.  It was thanks to those that were commenting that got me thinking in the right direction so thank you @jonrsharpe and @BorisLobanov.

So apparently the update [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) wasn't firing and `input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));` wasn't making it so.  That was the first clue.  I had to make sure that the event fires in order for the call to the service to be reached.

In order to do this I was already grabbing the `componentInstance' of the component from the TestBed.

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewUserComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 }
```

In order to get the event to fire, I needed to access the field's underlying [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) grab its update EventEmitter and emit something.

So in my test I've added this line:

```js
 component.username.update.emit(null);
```

This got my field to run the debounced subscribe function attached to the event.

This however did not fix the entire problem, running the test gave me a cannot execute `subscribe` on undefined.  The subscribe causing the error was the one attached to the service call `this._loginSrvc.chkUser(data).subscribe((...)=>{...})`.

After hours of fiddling with Observables and recreating my mocked services I finally stumbled upon a stackoverflow answer in another question that stated simple to remember to add `.and.callThrough()` when spying on a service's method.  OMG! How could I have forgotten that (slaps hand against forehead).  The subscribe wasn't functioning because the `spyOn(service,'chkUser')` was stopping the execution of the actual method, so there was no Observable to subscribe too.  In every example I saw that was attempting to do something similar never did they add the `.and.callThrough()` to their spy so it never occurred to me even the countless times I've used this before.

Anyway here's the working test:

```js
it('should check for username availability',fakeAsync(()=>{
  spyOn(service,'chkUser').and.callThrough();

  let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#username')).nativeElement;
  expect(input.value).toBe('');
  expect(component.username.value).toBe(null);

  input.value = user.username;

  component.username.update.emit(null);

  tick(500);

  expect(service.chkUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```